# How to make page transitions with a link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are cards on the homepage where I list the policies. Above these cards is a button called "details". I want to go to the detail of the product when I press this button. But a product can only have one type. For example,

> if it is a vehicle policy, the link should be: **/policies/vehicle/detail**

> if it is a housing policy, the link should be: **/policies/housing/detail**

More than one product can be displayed on the Home Page.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: history.location.pathname + activePolicies.policyGroup + '/details', state: { policy: activePolicy } }}>
  {t('general.details')}
  <AS.KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
</Link>
```

Since activePolicies is an array, I cannot place it as **activePolicies.policyGroup.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

using a var to solve it just like :

```
const path = condition ? 'vehicle': 'housing';
const link = `link you want`
```